# Minimizing Dimensions given the Area

Tags: calculus, optimization

I've been really struggling to figure out this question.

"The total enclosure around the playground at a daycare is to be $800$ square feet. One side of the playground is bordered by the school building while the three remaining sides will be enclosed with fencing.Find the dimensions that minimze the amount of fencing needed.

The answers I got were  width=$\sqrt{300}$ and length = $\frac{\sqrt{40}}6$. When I checked if they were right by multiplying width by height, I didn't get $800$, so I think it's wrong.

What can I do to solve this question? Thanks.

Comment: This is not a completely well formed problem in that an implied assumption is that any result will not be longer than the length of the side of the school building. As the answer by Parcly Taxel shows, a result of $40$ feet will likely not be an issue in real life, but I believe some sort of indication in the problem statement of this would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The question implies that the enclosure is a rectangle. Suppose the side length parallel to the school building's face is $h$, then the other side length is $\frac{800}h$ and we want to minimise $h+\frac{1600}h$.

The derivative of this is $1-\frac{1600}{h^2}$ and this is zero when $h=40$. Thus the enclosure should be $40$ feet long across the building face and $20$ feet wide to minimise the fencing (which will be $80$ feet in this case).

Comment: Note an implied assumption is that the side of the school building is at least $40$ feet. If not, this will impose an additional constraint which will, of course, give a different answer. However, it's not unreasonable to assume a school building side is at least $40$ feet long, so this will not normally be an issue.